# Comparing a group in time

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm working on my writing skill, trying to compare a situation in past and now for a group of people. Not sure if I'm saying it correct. But my intention is to say younger people at the time we are living in spend more time compared to those in 10 years ago. (i.e. in a more native and solid way)

Current idea:

> To illustrate, younger people waste more time on Facebook compared to their peers used to do.

If it's right, I want to know why it's right? or the other way round?

I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They waste more time on FB than their peers used to [waste on FB].

**In a comparative**, you just use *used to, or used to [verb]*

used to do is wrong there.

*They used to do* that.